Weekly topic challenge: call for proposals
This is the call for proposals for the weekly topic challenge. Answers to this question should be proposals for the weekly topic.
What is it?
There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on.
How does it work?

Each answer below should be a proposal for the weekly topic.
Upvote topics you'd like to see; downvote those you wouldn't.
Each week, probably Sunday or Monday, I will choose from among the proposed topics, and the challenge will begin: thinking of and posting good questions in the main site on that topic.

What do I win?
An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.
Who came up with this idea, anyway?
This was mentioned in a SO blog post, in reference to Jewish Life & Learning's original proposal.
How can I be notified of new challenges?

Check back on Meta from time to time, particularly on Sunday or Monday, to see if there's a new challenge post.
Check Meta's weekly-topic-challenge tag to see only the posts in the challenge (with the current challenge at the top of the list), or check Meta's featured tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events (including the current challenge).
To see just the current challenge, use this search.
If you use a blog-reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the feeds for weekly-topic-challenge or featured to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted.


It's still early so I'm not sure, but my feeling is the best topics would be those that currently do not have many questions under their tag.

We can also go the other way around. Option trading/pricing/theory is a very popular topic that new visitors continue to find interesting. It would be nice if we can point them to some canonical answers.
What do you guys think?

Looks like we have a tie... How do we determine the "winner" of last week's?

Signal weighting (i.e. blending factors). I am surprised there is no tag for this although there has a lot of attention in the literature

Signal weighting seems like a part of portfolio management.  Can you suggest a more descriptive and succinct tag/topic title?  Should we make the topic a bit broader, including all of portfolio management?

It certainly is a part of the portfolio management process. I think "signal weighting" refers to a very specific step in the portfolio construction process. I can offer a definition borrowed from Grinold: "Signal weighting is the challenge of combining information from different sources in order to maximize that information's after-cost effectiveness.".  It is more specific than "portfolio management" which includes variety of steps

Do you think we can come up with multiple questions on signal weighting, or shall we broaden it to portfolio management?

transaction-costs
Currently 1 question.

limit-order-book
Currently 8 questions.

optimization
Currently 13 questions.

risk-management
Currently 21 questions.

anomalies
Currently 1 question (possibly more untagged).
